# Operator Theory Textbook Question

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I read the following excerpt in my course textbook:

[image]

Now, I'm led to believe that $P:X\rightarrow X$ as above is bounded iff $M$ and $N$ are both closed. I understand the only if direction, but I can't put my finger on how $M$ and $N$ closed $\implies$ $P$ is bounded. Could somebody kindly provide a sketch proof? Thanks

Comment: If someone knows where i can read proof of the opposite direction,that is if M,N are closed follows thagt projection is bounded please give me the link. I woula appreciate a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $P$ is a projection, then $M$ and $N$ are complementary in $X$. In fact, $x = (I - P)x + Px$ for all $x\in X$, and we have $\mbox{Ker}\,P=(I-P)(X)$ and $\mbox{Im}\,P = P(X)$.

Your claim is true in Banach spaces, not in normed spaces in general. Let's see why.

Assume $X$ is Banach. Suppose $\{ x_n \} \subseteq X$ converges to $x \in X$ and that $\{ P x_n \}$ converges to some $y$. Then $x_n - Px_n = (I-P)x_n$ converges to $x - y$. It follows that $y \in M$ and $x-y \in N$, so $y = Py = Px$. Hence the conclusion follows from the closed graph theorem.

Now, suppose $X$ is a normed space, but not complete. For instance, take $X$ the subspace of $\ell^\infty$ of finetely nonzero sequences and take $\{ s_n \}$ an unbounded sequence of scalars. Define $P$ as

$$P(a_n) = ( a_1 + s_1 a_2, 0, a_3 + s_2 a_4, 0, a_5 + s_3 a_6, \dots ) \qquad (\{a_n\} \in X).$$

Then $P$ is a projection (is linear and $P^2 = P$). Also

$$\mbox{Im}\,P = \{ \{a_n\} : \{a_n\} \in X, a_{2n} = 0 \mbox{ for each } n \in \mathbb N \},$$

and

$$\mbox{Ker}\,P = \{ \{a_n\} : \{a_n\} \in X, a_{2n-1} + s_n a_{2n} = 0 \mbox{ for each } n \in \mathbb N \}.$$

Then $\mbox{Ker}\,P$ and $\mbox{Im}\,P$ are complementary in $X$ and both are closed, but $P$ is not bounded.

Comment: Hello, i have a question what menas that M and N are complementary?

Comment: Could you please help with a proof or give a literature where i could read a proof in the opposite direction. That is N,M are closed implies that projection is bounded?? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just from that statement (and not really having a grasp of the subject material) I would *not* imply this:

"If the range $M$ and the null space $N$ of $P$ are closed subspaces of (normed space) $X$, then $P$ is a bounded projection operator on $X$."

That's the converse of what's in the last sentence, as far as I can see.  The converse does not necessarily follow from the statement.  It *can* -- and that's the if *and only if* part -- but it doesn't have to.

Comment: I read elsewhere that this was in fact an iff statement. I just haven't been able to think up/find a satisfactory proof for the converse.