# Proving projection operators are bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $X$ is the direct sum of two normed linear spaces $X_1,X_2$, ($X=X_1 \dot{+} X_2$). Then I need to prove the projection operators $\Pi_1:X \to X_1$ and $\Pi_2:X \to X_2$ are bounded $\Longleftrightarrow$ both $X_1,X_2$ are closed on $X$.

On proving for $\Longrightarrow$]
I've tried supposing that if {$x_{1n}$} is a sequence of $X_1$ that converges to an element  $x_1\in X$ then I need to prove that $x_1\in X_1$.
To do this, we have the following $\parallel\Pi_1 x_{1n}\parallel_{X_1}\leq M\parallel x_{1n}\parallel_X$ (given the boundedness of $\Pi_1$), then if I take limit as $n\to \infty$ then we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \parallel x_{1n}\parallel_{X_1}\leq Mx$ which would mean that {$x_{1n}$} converges in $X_1$

Please  help me out on solving this and the other direction as well

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/664155/