# Limit of a sequence in direct sum of normed vector spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $W$ a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Let $V,U \subset W$ be two subsets of $W$ such that $W = V \oplus U$

Let $\{w_m\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \subset W$ be a sequence in $W$ such that $w_m \to w_0 \in W$

$\forall m \in \mathbb{N}: w_m =v_m + u_m$ with $v_m \in V$ and $u_m \in U$

I would like to know if is it true that $v_m \to v_0 \in V$ and $u_m \to u_0 \in U$ and $w_0 =v_0+u_0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conclusion is certainly valid if $W$ is assumed to be a Banach space and $U, V$ its closed subspaces.

Define $P : W \to U$ as the projection on $U$, meaning if $x \in W$ has the unique decomposition $x= u + v$, with $u \in U$, $v \in V$ then $Px = u$.

Notice that $I - P : W \to V$ is the projection on $V$, i.e. $(I - P)x = v$.

$P$ is obviously linear. Is is also bounded by the Closed Graph Theorem:

Assume $w_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} w_0$ and $Pw_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} u' \in U$ (since $U$ is closed).

Then by linearity of the limit we get

$$\underbrace{(I-P)w_m}_{\in V} = w_m - Pw_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} w_0 - u' \in V$$

The sequence $((I-P)w_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ is in $V$ then so is its limit $w_0 - u' \in V$ because $V$ is closed.

Hence $w_0 = \underbrace{u'}_{\in U} + \underbrace{(w_0 - u')}_{\in V}$. By the uniqueness of the decomposition, we conclude $u' = u$, therefore the graph of $P$ is closed.

We conclude that $P$ is a bounded linear map, and so is $I - P$. They are therefore continuous so

$$w_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} w_0$$
implies

$$u_m = Pw_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} Pw_0 = u$$
$$v_m = (I-P)w_m \xrightarrow{m\to\infty} (I-P)w_0 = v$$

Comment: thanks for your answer and proof, so if $W$ isn't a Banach space we can't say that it is true?

Comment: @MateyMath I'm not sure, but an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/664155/144766) gives an example where $P$ is not bounded, so perhaps try with that.

Comment: ok @mechanodroid thanks for that example